# How to Populate GridView from Repeater Label Button on_click

Tags: c#, asp.net

I gave my "LabelButtons" a value which would be the "ID" for them and it outputs the text name so people see "product1", "product2" etc... but its really defined by the "ID" I need to take that "ID" when the button is clicked and output on my GridView the data that corresponds with the ID Value. How do I make it that when I click on button it will populate the gridview to give me the information I am looking for? I am sorry if this is not clear enough I will give more detail if needed. Also, I have my hiddenfield trying to hold the value for the data of the button click and it always stays null instead of taking the value of the button click id.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using TropicalServer.BAL;


namespace TropicalServer.UI
{
    public partial class Products : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                BindData();
            }        
        }
        protected void BindData()
        {
            DataSet dsID = new BALGetItems().GetItemTypeData();
            rptrProductCategories.DataSource = dsID;
            rptrProductCategories.DataBind();
        }

        protected void Repeater1_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            HiddenField hf = (HiddenField)e.Item.FindControl("hf");
            LinkButton cat = (LinkButton)e.Item.FindControl("lbPC");       
            hf.Value = Convert.ToString(e.CommandArgument);
            PopulateGrid(new BALGetItems().GetItemData(Convert.ToInt32(hf.Value)));
        }

        private void PopulateGrid(DataSet ds)
        {
            int value = 0;
            if (Cache["Data"] == null)
            {
                DataSet dsID = new BALGetItems().GetItemData(value);
                Cache["Data"] = dsID;
                gvPC.DataSource = dsID;
                gvPC.DataBind();
            }
            else
            {
                gvPC.DataSource = (DataSet)Cache["Data"];
                gvPC.DataBind();
            }  
        }
    }







 <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage/TropicalServer.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Products.aspx.cs" Inherits="TropicalServer.UI.Products" %>

    <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
    </asp:Content>
    <asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
        <! DOCTYPE html>`enter code here`
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head id="Head2">
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="~/AppThemes/TropicalStyles/Products.css" />
        <title>ServerLogin</title>
    </head>
        <body>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblPC" class="productCategories" runat="server" Text="Product Categories"></asp:Label>
                        </div>
                        <div >
                            <asp:Repeater ID="rptrProductCategories" runat="server" OnItemCommand="Repeater1_ItemCommand">
                                <ItemTemplate>    
                                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lbPC" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container,"DataItem.ItemTypeID") %>' Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container,"DataItem.ItemTypeDescription")%>'/><br />
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:Repeater>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="dataGrid">
                            <asp:GridView ID="gvPC" runat="server" PagerSettings-PageButtonCount="5" AutoGenerateColumns="False" PageSize="5" AllowPaging="True" EnableSortingAndPagingCallbacks="True" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#336666" BorderStyle="Double" BorderWidth="3px" CellPadding="4" GridLines="Horizontal">
                                <Columns>
                                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="ItemNumber" DataField="ItemNumber"/>
                                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="ItemDescription" DataField="ItemDescription" />
                                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Pre-Price" DataField="PrePrice" />
                                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Size" DataField="ItemUnits" />
                                </Columns>
                                <FooterStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#333333" />
                                <HeaderStyle BackColor="#336666" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />

    <PagerSettings PageButtonCount="5"></PagerSettings>
                                <PagerStyle BackColor="#336666" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                <RowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#333333" />
                                <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#339966" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                                <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F7F7F7" />
                                <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#487575" />
                                <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E5E5E5" />
                                <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#275353" />
                            </asp:GridView>
     <asp:HiddenField ID="hf" runat="server"/>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </body>
    </html>
    </asp:Content>
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Sorry about that I will remember next time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, your LinkButton needs an `OnClick` event.

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lbPC" runat="server" 
     CommandArgument='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container,"DataItem.ItemTypeID") %>' 
     Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container,"DataItem.ItemTypeDescription")%>'
     OnClick="lbPC_Click"></asp:LinkButton>
```

Then in your click event, grab the ID, retrieve the data for your GridView, then bind the GridView.

```
protected void lbPC_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LinkButton lbPC = (LinkButton)sender;
    int id = int.Parse(lbPC.CommandArgument)

    //If for some reason you do need to hold the ID value in your hiddenfield, 
    //just call it as is. There is no need for FindControl() since it is
    //outside of both your Repeater and your GridView.
    hf.Value = id.ToString();

    gvPC.DataSource = YourDataRetrievalMethod(id);
    gvPC.DataBind();
}
```